# Jlist doesn't refresh

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, custom-controls, jlist

I have a main jFrame and have added custom jPanels to the frame. Using a cardLayout I switch between the panels based on what the user clicks/types.

At one point the user is able to search for a recipe and the results are added to a jList in a JScrollPane. The separate panel is then displayed that should show the results. The problem is the results are never displayed. I think it's a matter of refreshing but I'm not familiar with swing.

Here's the code for the actual method that does this work:

```
 public ArrayList<Menu> menuListResults(SearchParameters p) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

    ArrayList<Menu> searchResults = new ArrayList();

    // Test Menu Object
    LocalDate menu_date = LocalDate.now();
    Menu m1 = new Menu(12463, "", "HOTEL EASTMAN", "BREAKFAST", "COMMERCIAL", "HOT SPRINGS, AR",
            "CARD; 4.75X7.5", "EASTER", "", "1900-2822", "" , "", menu_date, "Hotel Eastman", "", "",
            "", "UNDER REVIEW", 2, 67);
    searchResults.add(m1);      

    if (searchResults == null || searchResults.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No menus returned from that search!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    else {
        for (Menu searchResult : searchResults) {
            model.addElement(searchResult);
        }
    }

    menusList.setModel(model);
    this.jScrollPane1.repaint();
    return searchResults;
}
```

Comment: in JList API for DefaultListModel are implemented Object (new String, Integer ...) and Vector(Vector<Object>)

Comment: read Oracle tutorial - How to use lists, for detailed description and working code example

Comment: Try and provide us a code snippet of the very smallest that displays your problem. A specific in how one uses CardLayout, when adding a card to the deck or parent CardLayout panel, the syntax is deck.add(card, "resultPanel");.

Then to show that panel the syntax is CardLayoutobject.show(deck, "resultPanel");. Yes, initializing the CardLayout LayoutManager is one way to do it.